# When I connect to my VPN my proxy settings do not work

Tags: windows-10, vpn, proxy, proxy-server

Just as the title says. I have PlexVPN, when I connect to my VPN the proxy settings don't work and I cannot connect to the internet. I can't use chrome or any other application and I am lost why. It says "The remote device or resource won't accept the connection" it tells me to change my proxy settings and turn off the proxy server, when I do it still does not work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The proxy might not work inside the VPN. If the VPN doesn't work without the proxy, then there is a problem with it, and you could address its support.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean your proxy settings? If youre reffering to the app itself then im not sure if i can help, but just to make it clear vpns are not the same as proxy, so if you configured it manually, theres going to be different settings for it i believe.

If you cant get it to work you could try PureVPN since theres an 88% Off on it for New Years.